# How to fix this Git-LFS 'rev-list' migration error

Tags: git, git-lfs

I am trying to install Git-LFS and then migrating our repo.
I installed LFS and that was OK.
I added several file types, that appeared OK.
Since our repo is old/mature, I went to `migrate` the file types I added, and got the below error. The files or types I specified didn't always exist in the app, and certainly not in the 0.0.1 tag (super beta) as the app is now mature (ie v11+ over 5+ years).
My question is, what do I do now?
(I'm not a git-ninja so please be explicit with suggestions or commands, thx)

```
paveglioc-mbp:AWKit paveglioc$ git lfs migrate import --include="*.a"
migrate: Fetching remote refs: ..., done                                        
Error in git rev-list --stdin --reverse --topo-order --do-walk --: exit status 128 fatal: bad revision '^refs/remotes/tags/origin/0.0.1'
```

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I haven't revisited it (just went along with no LFS support), but there was a 2.6.x version update IIRC that might fix this.